# How do I get the location of a UI touch in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, sprite-kit

I would like to get the location of the touch in the UI, and use that location to determine what direction the sprite runs. For example, if the touch is on the left side of the screen, the user runs left, and if the touch is on the right side of the screen, the user runs right.

Comment: There are a lot of examples here on SO about that. Just use search.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.locationInView(view)
        print(position)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is SpriteKit,  you should be using `locationInNode(scene)`

Comment: Swift 4.0 --> override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let position = touch.location(in: self)
            print(position)
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

@KnightOfDragon's answer is the right one here.

You should use directly

```
func locationInNode(_ node: SKNode) -> CGPoint
```

More about Touch events in SpriteKit over here: [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006785-CH3-SW21)

Answer (score 1):

As KnightOfDragon mentioned for SpriteKit the correct way would be

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self) // self is the current SKScene
        let node = nodeAtPoint(location)

        // To get the touched half of the screen I do this
        if location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
             // left half touched, do something
        }

        if location.x > CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
            // right half touched, do something
        }
    }
}
```